# Get the path to the local repository inside a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm new to maven and I'm trying to build my first maven plugin,
In my plugin i want to determine the path to the project's dependencies, but I'm not seeing anyway to access the path to the `localRepository`.

I have tried the following methods:

- `MavenSession.getLocalRepository().getUrl()`
- `MavenSession.getRequest().getLocalRepositoryPath().getAbsolutePath()`
- `MavenSession.getRepositorySession().getLocalRepository().getBasedir().getAbsolutePath()`

But they all return null upon calling `getLocalRepository()`, I also searched everywhere on the net but did not find any clue of how it's done.

here is the project's pom which I'm running my plugin on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.evalia.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>evalia-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Evalia project</name>

  <properties>
    <author>Developer one</author>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.evalia.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is my base goal which other goals should extend:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.model.Dependency;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;


/**
 * Loads project dependencies which is run on.
 */
public abstract class AbstractDependencyLoaderMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    
    /**
     * the pom model as MavenProject
     */
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", property = "session", required = true, readonly = true)
    private MavenSession session;


    /**
     * filters dependencies to be loaded using their groupIds
     */
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "", property = "groups", required = false)
    private String groupIds;

    /**
     * filters dependencies to be loaded using their artifactIds
     */
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "", property = "artifacts", required = false)
    private String artifactIds;


    private void injectDependencies(MavenProject project, String repoPath) throws MojoFailureException, MojoExecutionException {

        List<Dependency> dependencies = project.getDependencies();

        GroupIdFilter groupIdFilter = new GroupIdFilter(groupIds);
        ArtifactIdFilter artifactIdFilter = new ArtifactIdFilter(artifactIds);

        if(groupIdFilter.isPresent()){
            dependencies.removeIf(groupIdFilter);
        }

        if(artifactIdFilter.isPresent()){
            dependencies.removeIf(artifactIdFilter);
        }

        List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Dependency dependency: dependencies){
            urls.add(ClasspathUtils.mapToUrl(repoPath, dependency));
        }

        updateClasspath(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]));
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private void updateClasspath(URL... urls) throws MojoExecutionException{
        try {
            ClassLoader parent = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, parent);
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Something went wrong, " +
            "see the below stacktrace for more information!", e);
        }
    }


    public void execute() throws MojoFailureException, MojoExecutionException {
        MavenProject project = session.getTopLevelProject();
        String localRepoPath = null; //Here i want to resolve the path to the local repository
        try {
            injectDependencies(project, localRepoPath);
            postExecute(project);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MojoFailureException("Something went wrong", e);
        }
    }

    public abstract void postExecute(MavenProject project) throws MojoFailureException, MojoExecutionException;

}
```

Any ideas ?

And thank you.

Comment: Why do you need it? What is your plugin going to do with that?

Comment: Can you please show the source code of your mojo? Also as already asked why do you need the access to the local repository? Can explain what you like to achieve?

Comment: my requirement is that the plugin needs to be able to get the database driver from the project and add it to the classpath to be able to initialize the driver and execute some sql commands, i know that this is possible with the `sql:execute` goal but in case of sql:execute the drivers are not found and you need to add them as dependencies in the plugins definition section in your project's pom which is a no go for what im trying to do, so yeah i want to get the full path to the dependency jar and add it to the classpath using the `URLClassLoader`, source code will be added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

## MOJO class

```
package com.acme;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession;

@Mojo(name = "dummy", requiresProject = false)
public class DummyMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${repositorySystemSession}", readonly = true)
    protected RepositorySystemSession repoSession;
    
    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        getLog().info("" + repoSession.getLocalRepository().getBasedir());
    }
}
```

## POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

After running `mvn install` i can execute the plugin using `mvn com.acme:dummy-maven-plugin:1-SNAPSHOT:dummy` and it outputs the path to my local repository correctly.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work the `RepositorySystemSession.getLocalRepository()` returns `null`

Comment: This is very strange. There isn't any special about this. My plugin is fairly simple. It has just three Maven dependencies: org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.8.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.8.7 and org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:3.7.0 each with scope provided, for building I only have the usual suspects in my pluginManagement: maven-compiler-plugin, maven-resources-plugin and maven-plugin-plugin.

Comment: Can you please add your MOJO class.

Comment: Yes i updated my question with the mojo class which is an abstract class meant to be extended by goal classes

Comment: I edited my answer. Now you can create a complete Maven project out of it. Just put the POM into a directory dummy-maven-plugin and the MOJO class into dummy-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/acme.

Comment: after testing your code i found out the problem, in fact i was running my plugin in a unit test using `MojoRule.lookupConfiguredMojo(pom, goal)` which leads to most of the properties and settings in maven to be loaded as `null` (i still don't know why though), so when i tried it from the command line like you mentioned it worked like charm, thanx